# Handling 'Windows' type data in grep

Tags: bash, unix, search, grep

I have a file (test) with contents like this:

```
win2k31       8506 KB   D:\Program Files (x86)
win2k31       6256 KB   D:\98fdac7656d6632b28
win2k31       3110 KB   C:\Program Files\Microsoft
win2k31         14 KB   C:\Program Files\Zero G Registry
```

and I've to run a pattern search in it using grep, but it doesn't seem to work. For e.g.:

```
#grep 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft' test
win2k31       3110 KB   C:\Program Files\Microsoft
```

'grep' did a fine search, but if I put the pattern in a variable {$var}, it fails or does improper search

```
#var='C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft'
#echo $var
C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft
#grep $var test
grep: Files\\Microsoft: No such file or directory
test:win2k31       3110 KB   C:\Program Files\Microsoft
test:win2k31         14 KB   C:\Program Files\Zero G Registry
```

Above shows that 'grep' did a search for 'C:\Program' only and showd an error for the 'Files\Microsoft' part as it has space.
Then if I put in extra quotes ('), it fails again.

```
#var=\''C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft'\'
#echo $var
'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft'
#grep $var test
grep: Files\\Microsoft': No such file or directory
```

What am I missing here ? Why putting the pattern in a variable not working for grep ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try enclosing `grep` search pattern `$var` with double-quotes `"`

```
var='C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft'
grep "$var" test
```

Output:

```
win2k31       3110 KB   C:\Program Files\Microsoft
```

It's best practice to enclose `grep/sed` search pattern with

1. single-quotes `'` in case of no variable substition
2. double-quotes `"` in case of desired variable substitution

Comment: Yes, it worked... suprisingly...I tried it earlier and it didn't give the right output, probably I missed something..

Comment: @Marcos happens! In this context, I found these articles interesting in case you want to have a look [Leaning_toothpick_syndrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaning_toothpick_syndrome), [String_literal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_literal)

Comment: @Marcos what's the intention here? replace `\\` with something what?

Comment: To replace one (\) with two (\\), so that it can work better with grep

Comment: @Marcos In that case escape it `sed -e 's_\\_\\\\_g'`. Not the use of single quote instead of double quote.